# Which bacteria have the highest mutation rate?

Tags: genetics, bacteriology, replication, mutations

From my reading on *M. tuberculosis*, I know that this organism has a pretty high mutation rate due to uncorrected sloppy replication, which leads to a high rate of development of spontaneous resistance to treatment.

Are there species that can beat *M. tuberculosis* in this degree of mutation, due to polymerase sloppiness or other mechanism?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "sloppiness" under normal conditions, or are you talking about in the presence of antibiotics like Moxifloxacin?

Comment: Indeed, the above was from memory. After a second look it appears that it's mainly a sloppiness during DNA repair following UV and especially oxidative stress. (PMID 12705867 and 21516081)

Comment: the other way of having a high mutation rate is to be around a lot of ionizing radiation like D radiodurans... it is true that organisms 'throttle' their mutation rate by changing up their dna repair systems. Darwin's gas pedal...  Given that fewer than 0.1% of the bacteria are known that exist (0.001%? the jury is still out), its possible some amazing discoveries will turn up later too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that mutation rates are somehow constant over evolutionary time. They are not. Mutation rates will change according to the stresses a species is subjected to. If you take a bacterial population and place it in a stressful environment (high/low temperatures, oxidative stress, lack of nourishment or whatever) you are likely to see an increase in the mutation rate.

That said, this review and references therein might interest you:

[E. Denamur and I. Matic,Evolution of mutation rates in bacteria,*Molecular Microbiology* **60**(4), pages 820–827, May 2006](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2958.2006.05150.x/full)

Answer (score 2):

> From my reading on M. tuberculosis, I know that this organism has a pretty high mutation rate

Huh, that's news to me. In fact, Mtb has a rather low mutation rate and rather low genetic variance. See the paper by [Sherman & Gagneux](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v43/n5/full/ng.815.html) in Nature genetics. The paper does state that mutation rate in latent infection is higher than expected or previously assumed, but that's a different story.

That said, mutation rate depends strongly on the genomic context. You can have mutator strains in *E. coli* or other bacteria that exceed the mutation rates of other strains by orders of magnitude.

A clinical example of a bacterium with mutator strains that help in acquiring resistance is *Pseudomonas aeruginosa*. More on that in the paper by [Ferroni et al.](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v43/n5/full/ng.815.html).